# Orthogonal reflexive relationships

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make reflexive relationships in a UML diagram look good.  Making the line orthogonal doesn't seem to work.  It makes it straight with 3 line segments, but not orthogonal.  I can't seem to add waypoints either.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Could you paste the diagram XML (File->Edit) into pastebin and link it here so I can see what you mean please?